# Read log files in cygwin (GUI) windows 7 through ssh

Tags: cygwin

I have goggled a lot on this topic but I couldn't find what I was looking for. I am currently using ssh to log into a server at work. I need to read some log files now and using `cat` is very exhausting.I therefore installed `putclip` but I could'nt use `putclip` when I am sshed into the server.I then tried `cygstart` but that doesnt even work when I am sshd in the server. Any suggestions on how I could use notepad to read files from the server that I am sshd into ??

Answer (score 0):

Could you use scp to just copy the file locally?

Another option would be, from cygwin,

```
ssh user@server cat $FILE > localFile.log
```

This should cat out the file and write it to a local file.